# App Rejected for using other platform names

Tags: ios, app-store

My app got rejected due to using other platform names and got the message:

> 3.1 - Apps or metadata that mentions the name of any other mobile platform will be rejected

The other platform names include Facebook, Skype, iTunes, Google Play, etc. I cannot omit these names as users are buying vouchers for these specific names.

Is there any way around this?

Comment: I wouldn't have called the three names you mention "mobile platforms".  Are you sure those are they ones causing the rejection?  (Maybe you could ask if the reviewer wasn't specific.)

Comment: I also have google play store name there as i am also allowing users to buy vouchers for them .

Answer (score 1):

No, there is no way around this. I've seen people try putting the words into their screenshots rather than their description, and try writing lots of description text in the hope Apple don't notice. Both times they got caught. The only thing – *that I would **really** not recommend* – is to amend your description after Apple approval.

You say the other platform names "include" Facebook and Skype, which are probably OK. You might find it easiest just to remove the worst offenders, as it were – Android, for example, won't ever get through.

Comment: *argh* Yes i have a google play logo in my screen for letting my users buy a voucher for them .

Comment: how it is a fix as i have to remove this functionality from my app ?

Comment: That is the only possible solution here, I'm afraid. It may not be a fix you like, but it's the only one that is possible if you want to ship your app on iOS.

Comment: You're welcome; please mark the answer as correct so others can benefit.